# How do I set self as delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

When the user pushes the button in ViewController1, I want it to call a function in ViewController2. I think the only thing I'm missing is assigning ViewController2 as its own delegate, but how do you declare self as delegate?

**ViewController1**

```
protocol VC1Delegate {
    func pushThisButton(_ sender: UIButton)
}

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    var delegate: VC1Delegate!
    var theButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buildButton()

    }

    func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate.pushThisButton(theButton)
    }

    func buildButton() {
        theButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
        theButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pushButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(theButton)
    }

}
```

**View Controller 2**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, VC1Delegate {

    // I'm guessing somewhere here I need to declare myself as the delegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func pushThisButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Damnit, Jack! Push the damn button!")
    }

}
```

Comment: you need declare a protocol, in some part of your code you need assing the delegate property of your  ViewController1 this typically is done in the ViewController2 presentation, something like `viewController1.delegate = viewController2`  also you need use weak after var for your delegate, if not you will have a retain cycle and your app will have memory issues

Comment: Sorry, I left out the protocol by accident. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you instantiate VC2, you should assign delegate to it.
For example:

```
 protocol VC1Delegate: class {
     func pushThisButton(_ sender: UIButton)
 }

 class ViewController1: UIViewController {

     weak var delegate: VC1Delegate?
```

...

```
let vc2 = ViewController2() 
self.delegate = vc2 // we are in the VC1 context 
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```

Comment: I think actually is vc1 which have .delegate property

Comment: in fact should be `self.delegate = vc2` // we are in the VC1 context

Comment: Yes, sure. Fixed.

Comment: add in your answer the weak var delegate observation, is needed if you want to avoid memory issues caused by retain cycles

Comment: Also I think construction should be inverted, like this: https://gist.github.com/helloworlt/fb15419ba2786d0a9c688bc6c565cc74

Comment: Works beautifully, but without "weak". Error: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not VC1Delegate.

Comment: @thismeanswar Fixed.